# Monotouch use UITabBarController inside DialogViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, tabbarcontroller, dialogviewcontroller

Currently in my app I have this design:

-- DialogViewController 1

-----DialogViewController 2

--------DialogViewController 3

-----------TabBarController

--------------DialogViewController4

--------------DialogViewController5

--------------DialogViewController6

--------------DialogViewController7

Problem with this is that dialog view controllers 4-7 breaks the monotouch dialog flow (so to speak), because of TabBarController in between. When I create dialog view controllers 4-7 I need to create new Root in their constructors which I don't need to for DVC 1-3.

With this approach certain things like radio groups don't work inside DVC 4-7 e.g it will display the radio group selection, but there is no navigation bar at the top.

My question is what can I do to solve this? Can I use TabBarController inside DVC somehow if that makes sense? Or how can I "hook" DVC 4-7 back to main "circuit"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [iOS HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52)

> A tab bar appears at the bottom edge of the screen and should be
>   accessible from every location in the app

which implies that it should be the root, not nested inside another controller.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I'm stuck, no idea how to solve this problem. :(

Comment: I wonder why Apple is discouraging from using UITabBarController in other places instead of root controller? You would think that many applications could benefit from having UITabBarController at any level.